# bag and balls using combinatorics

Tags: probability, combinatorics

can i use the rule of #of favorable cases/#of possible cases in this exercice :
we have a bag that contains 4 white balls and 2 red balls, if we pick a white ball we should remove it from the bag , if we pick a red ball we put it again in the bag. we take 3 balls form the bag.
what is the probability that we get only one white ball.
ps: i know that this problem can be solved using multiplication of probabilities in each pick like if we want to get the probability of picking one white ball and its in the first pick we can do $（4/6）×（2/5）$＾2. but i just want to know if we can count all the possible cases and the favorable cases and use the rule above?

Comment: #favorable/#possible is **only** valid when the different possible cases referred to are equally likely to occur.  Surely, among the cases you would be counting as possible would have been for instance imagining the balls all being uniquely numbered and getting $W_1,W_2,W_3$ in that order as well as $R_1,R_1,R_1$ in that order.  These outcomes are not equally likely to have occurred however, the first occurring with probability $\frac{1}{6\cdot 5\cdot 4}$ while the second occurs with probability $\frac{1}{6^3}$.  I do not see a way to phrase this with equiprobable outcomes.

Comment: Warning: $\frac46\times\left(\frac25\right)^2$ does not equal the probability of first drawing a white ball and then - after removing this ball and drawing of 3 others - getting only one white ball. Btw, just met you on Quora.

Comment: i think you misread what i said i said the probability that the out come is WRR is 4/6 * (2/5)^2

Comment: thank you JMoravitz

Comment: Then you are correct if the 3 balls are replaced after being drawn. If they are not replaced (and that is how I understood it) then the probability equals $\frac46\frac25\frac14$